# Complexity of solving two different LP problems

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have one LP problem (LP1) to solve, where a term in a constraint is to be substituted after solving another LP problem (LP2) (with a different variable vector). Suppose I call the dimension of the variable vector in LP1 as $n$ and in LP2 as $m$. I know that the complexity of solving an LP problem is $O(n^3L)$ ($L$ is the input length). 
My doubt is : 1. Is it correct that the total complexity of solving the two LP problems together is $O((n^3+m^3)L)$? (I am worried that since I am substituting the optimal value of LP problem and thus, order is to be maintained, maybe it is to be multiplied)
2. $L$ here is the input size, so should it differ for the two problems? Or I should take it as the maximum of input size of LP1 and LP2?  
e.g. suppose the problem is
$$\min c^Tx \,\text{s.t.} \, a_1^Tx\leq b_1, a_i^Tx\leq b_i,i=2,\ldots n.$$
Here $a_1$ is the optimal value of another LP problem. So we solve that LP to get $a_1$, substitute in this LP.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a term in a constraint is to be substituted after solving another LP problem".  Can you find a way to define the problem mathematically?  Can you specify the inputs to the algorithm, how those inputs are specified, and what output you want the algorithm to produce?

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152891/755 - does this answer your question?

Comment: @D.W. the question referred by you talks about reducing the size, however, mine talks about overall complexity, the doubt is simply because we have to solve LP1 and then LP2.

Comment: That question tells you how to compute the running time when you run first one algorithm, then run another algorithm.  Apply the same ideas, but modified as necessary to your specific situation.

Comment: @D.W.I think I got it. Optimal value of LP1 is an input to LP2 and does not reduce the problem size. So we simply add the complexities to get `O((n^3+m^3)L)`, where `L` is the maximum of input sizes of LP1 and LP2. Hope I am right.

Comment: Hint: Let $L_1$ be the size of the input to LP1, $L_2$ be the size of the input to LP2 before substitution, and $L_3$ be the size of the input to LP2 after substitution.  Can you express the total running time in terms of $n,m,L_1,L_2,L_3$?  Now, can you find any upper bound on $L_3$ in terms of $n,m,L_1,L_2$?  Finally, can you find an upper bound on the total running time in terms of $n,m,L_1,L_2$?  What is the total input size of the problem, in terms of $L_1,L_2$?

Comment: @D.W. Total run time: `O(n^3L_1+m^3L_3) = O(n^3L_1+m^3(L_2+size(a_1))) = O(n^3L_1+m^3L_2)`, for overall steps, total input size: `L_1+L_2+size(a_1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We measure the running time of an algorithm $A$ as a function of the input *to that algorithm*, not as a measure of the length of inputs to any subroutines or subalgorithms that $A$ might invoke.

Let $L_1$ be the size of the input to LP1, $L_2$ be the size of the input to LP2 before substitution, and $L_3$ be the size of the input to LP2 after substitution.

By your assumptions, the time to solve LP1 is $O(n^3 L_1)$.  If this is true, it follows that the length (number of bits) needed to express the solution can be at most $O(n^3 L_1)$.  Therefore, $L_3 = L_2 + O(n^3 L_1)$, so the time to solve LP2 is $O(m^3 L_3) = O(m^3 L_2 + n^3 m^3 L_1)$, and the total time to solve both is $O(n^3 L_1 + m^3 L_2 + n^3 m^3 L_1)$.  The length of the input to the overall algorithm is $L_1 + L_2$, so as a function of $L_1 + L_2$, the best bound we can give on the total running time is $O(n^3 m^3 (L_1+L_2))$.

This assumes you are measuring running time in the bit-complexity model or the word RAM model.  However, I am not sure whether your $O(n^3 L)$ bound is actually in those models, or if it is an arithmetic model where it is assumed it is possible to do an operation on unlimited-length integers in $O(1)$ time.  If the latter, then the reasoning above is not valid.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer, could you please suggest any reference for these kinds of problems? It would be great.

Comment: @Cherryblossoms, I recommend reading a good algorithms textbook, e.g., Dasgupta Papadimitriou Vazirani, or CLRS.

Comment: could you please address one doubt, you say 'the length needed to express the solution can be at most O(n^3L1).' Is this a fact? I m asking as we are talking about time complexity, and then after we are bounding the length.

Comment: @Cherryblossoms, in the models of computation I listed, in each step of computation, we can output at most one bit / at most one word, so the running time is an upper bound on the length of the output.